# Firebase popup window closes after calling login

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

If I try to use Firebase simple login from a popup window in Firefox, the popup window closes itself and I never get logged in.  Everything works fine if the new window is not a popup (i.e. if it's just another tab).  Everything works fine in Chrome regardless of whether the new window is a popup or not.

Here is my first html file:

```
<script>

function chromeless() {
    var s = "width=" + 1200 + ",height=" + 200
    var win = window.open('http://localhost:5000/tests/login.html',null,s,true)
    return win
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="chromeless()">Launch app</a>
```

Here is login.html:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.1/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>

<button id="login-github" style="display: none">Log in with GitHub</button>

<script>

var ref = new Firebase('https://taskranger.firebaseio.com/')
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(err, user) {
  if(err)
    alert(err)
  else if(user)
    console.log('logged in:', user)
  else
    $('#login-github').show()
})

$('#login-github').click(function() { auth.login('github', { rememberMe: true }) })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by naming your popup window in your index.html:

```
<script>

function chromeless() {
    var s = "width=" + 1200 + ",height=" + 200
    var win = window.open('./login.html',"any_valid_window_name",s,true)
    return win
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="chromeless()">Launch app</a>
```